# How to define inferiority relation on natural numbers in a dependently typed lambda-calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

Girard's *System F* have the following definition for natural numbers :
$$
\mathbb N :=
\forall\alpha,
(\alpha\rightarrow\alpha)
\rightarrow
(\alpha\rightarrow\alpha)
$$

A dependent type system can have a similar definition based on dependent product (where $\mathbb T$ is the type of all types) :
$$
\mathbb N :=
\prod_{\alpha:\mathbb T}
(\alpha\rightarrow\alpha)
\rightarrow
(\alpha\rightarrow\alpha)
$$

Let's define the $\lambda$-term *successor* in this dependent type system :
$$
S :=
\lambda n^{\mathbb N}.
\lambda\alpha^{\mathbb T}.
\lambda s^{\alpha\rightarrow\alpha}.
\lambda z^\alpha.
s \bigl( n \alpha s z \bigr)
$$

We know that relation $\leq$ on natural numbers satisfies the following first order logic propositions :
$$
\forall m,
\forall n,
m \leq n \Rightarrow m \leq S n
$$
$$
\forall n,
n \leq n
$$

Can we define $\leq$ in our dependent type system like we defined $\mathbb N$ ? :
$$
\leq :=
\prod_{p:\mathbb N}
\prod_{q:\mathbb N}
\prod_{\alpha:\mathbb N\rightarrow(\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb T)}
\bigl(
\prod_{m:\mathbb N}
\prod_{n:\mathbb N}
(\alpha m n)
\rightarrow
(\alpha m (S n))
\bigr)
\rightarrow
\bigl(
\prod_{x:\mathbb N}
\alpha x x
\bigr)
\rightarrow
(\alpha p q)
$$

Or :
$$
\leq :=
\sum_{p:\mathbb N}
\prod_{q:\mathbb N}
\prod_{\alpha:\mathbb N\rightarrow(\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb T)}
\bigl(
\prod_{m:\mathbb N}
\prod_{n:\mathbb N}
(\alpha m n)
\rightarrow
(\alpha m (S n))
\bigr)
\rightarrow
\bigl(
\prod_{x:\mathbb N}
\alpha x x
\bigr)
\rightarrow
(\alpha p q)
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Night was helpful, I think I found the right definition :
$$
\leq :=
\lambda p^{\mathbb N}.
\lambda q^{\mathbb N}.
\Biggl(
\prod_{\alpha:\mathbb N\rightarrow(\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb T)}
\bigl(
\prod_{m:\mathbb N}
\prod_{n:\mathbb N}
(\alpha m n)
\rightarrow
(\alpha m (S n))
\bigr)
\rightarrow
\bigl(
\prod_{x:\mathbb N}
\alpha x x
\bigr)
\rightarrow
(\alpha p q)
\Biggr)
$$